# Subjunctive construction involving "that"

Tags: grammaticality, american-english

From a prep book for GMAT:

Note that you should ALWAYS just use the base form of the verb in such a subjunctive construction involving the "that" clause.

Wrong:

> she recommended that John **should take** the ferry.
>   she recommended that
>   John **takes** the ferry.
>   she recommended that John **had taken** the ferry.

Correct:

> she recommended that John **take** the ferry.

I understood this, but here is the question.

> In the most bizarre court case this mouth, the judge ruled *that two
>   ping-pong ball manufacturers **owed** restitution to four national
>   ping-pong teams for the illegal weighting of* the ping-pong balls in
>   an effort to fix the tournament.
>
> (A) that two ping-pong ball
>   manufacturers **owed** restitution to four national ping-pong teams for
>   the illegal weighting of
>   (B) ...

---

The correct choice is A, which is no mistake. However I thought the word **owed** should be **owe**

Isn't it true?

Comment: The way I see it: "she recommended that John take the ferry " Is talking about something that hasn't happened yet. She recommends him to do that. But we don't know if he will or not. Hence, the subjunctive. -Subjunctive usually talk about the world of things that may or may not happen, feeling, subjective things, etc-. However with the last example, it is talking about something that DID happen in the past. So I think this is why they just used the past tense. It is actually reported speech, not subjunctive.

Comment: @Enlasnubess thanks, I just read more about subjunctive mood, and I think I have a better understanding now :D

Comment: If you replace *owe* by *owed*, the former implies that the action will be done in a certain future, we don't know when, and when using the latter, the action is taken to be done in the present.